# recursive pseudocode: order of execution of print statements

Tags: recursion, pseudocode

I am not sure what the following code will print out. Can someone please explain in the best detail possible? Is this recursion?

```
void h ( int n )
   if ( n >=  4 )
      h ( n / 2 )
   end if 
   print n 
end h
```

What is printed when the call h (16) is executed?

Comment: We can't answer that with Pseudocode. Each language may handle the arguments differently.

Comment: What will be printed out and why? This is a practice test question that I am having trouble understanding.

Comment: We can't answer that question, as I already said. Your previous question and its answers should help you, though. You **need** to know whether `int n` is being passed by reference or by value, and it's impossible to know that from *Pseudocode*.

Comment: @AndrewBarber:  In what language can you pass `n/2` by reference?

Comment: @indiv That is actually a *fantastic* note to add, and I missed that detail. I'm going to reopen this, and you can consider answering it that way. Given that, I do see this as a different question, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not look at the output of the program for a small integer value, say `n == 42`? Here's a Python implementation of your pseudo-code:

```
def h(n):
    if n >= 4:
        h(n/2)
    print(n)
```

I am assuming that `n/2` means floating point division here, that part is unclear from your pseudo-code. `h(42)` will put out:

```
2.625
5.25
10.5
21.0
42
```

Here's whats happening:  First `n` is 42, and `42 >= 4`. Hence, `h(21)` is called. `21 >= 4`, so `h(10.5)` is called. `10.5 >= 4`, so `h(5.25)` is called. `5.25 >= 4`, so `h(2.625)` is called. Finally `2.625 < 4`, so there's not another call to `h`. Instead, 2.625 is printed. Now `h(2.625)` is finished and `h(5.25)` can continue and print `5.25`, and so on, until `h(42)` finishes the call-chain by printing 42. So to summarize what `h(n)` does: `h(n)` will continuously divide `n` by two until `n < 4`, then print the results of these divisions in reverse order.

You should be able to work out what `h(16)` will print now.